# Checking values with mass inserts

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Currently in my application I do an

```
INSERT INTO X (X1, X2)
VALUES ('Placeholder1','Placeholder'),
        ...
        ...
```

for my database when inserting multiple values.

However, some of these may end up being duplicates into the X table so currently I just use `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`, but I understand `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` tends to be looked down upon so I was wondering if there was do mass insertions while also doing individual checks for duplicates in a single query.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing a mass insertion from `VALUES` anyway, use a temp table or table variable or TVP instead

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate `not exists` in the query:

```
INSERT INTO X (X1, X2)
    SELECT v.*
    FROM (VALUES ('Placeholder1','Placeholder'),
                  ...
                  ...
         ) v(X1, X2)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM X
                      WHERE X.X1 = v.X1 AND X.X2 = v.X2
                     );
```